# If Else with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm trying to implement three conditions and four outcomes:

[image]

The values in Col I are driven by a data validation list in the master worksheet.

I tried the following:

```
If DataImport.Cells(i, "E").Value <> 0 And DataImport.Cells(i, "F").Value <> 0 And DataImport.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Hide" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = False
ElseIf DataImport.Cells(i, "E").Value = 0 And DataImport.Cells(i, "F").Value = 0 And DataImport.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Hide" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = False
ElseIf DataImport.Cells(i, "E").Value <> 0 And DataImport.Cells(i, "F").Value <> 0 And DataImport.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Unhide" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = True
ElseIf DataImport.Cells(i, "E").Value = 0 And DataImport.Cells(i, "F").Value = 0 And DataImport.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Unhide" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = False
```

The procedure is ignoring my third condition and is still showing related worksheets with "Hidden" in Column I.

Comment: What about an `End If`? Does you code compile at all? Secondly: Maybe there is a null value somewhere in the read out cells?

Answer (score 4):

Keep it simple. When I am working with complex logic, I set up variables first so my code is easier to read.

```
Option Explicit
Dim isNotZero as Boolean
Dim isToHide as Boolean
isNotZero = DataImport.Cells(i, "E").Value <> 0 And DataImport.Cells(i, "F").Value <> 0
isToHide = DataImport.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Hide"
```

Now, we can use these variables in your code (remember to indent properly so code logic is visible)

```
If isNotZero And isToHide Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = False
ElseIf DataImport.Cells(i, "E").Value = 0 And DataImport.Cells(i, "F").Value = 0 And isToHide Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = False
ElseIf isNotZero And Not isToHide Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = True
ElseIf DataImport.Cells(i, "E").Value = 0 And DataImport.Cells(i, "F").Value = 0 And Not isToHide Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = False
End iF
```

You notice how I have left some of the code. (A <> 0 **AND** B <> 0) is not the opposite of (A = 0 **AND** B = 0). What you were looking for there was (A = 0 **OR** B = 0). A simple truth table will prove this, and I am going to leave this as an exercise for yourself.

**But wait.**

Your logic/truth table above was a good thing to do. It shows the pattern of A and C (A and B are the values in E and F being non-zero). It also shows a simple pattern.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = isNotZero and Not isToHide
```

As you can see, I have replaced your complex `If … Then...` with a single line of code. Let us make one last tweak to `isToHide`, and your final code is below.

```
Option Explicit
Dim isNotZero as Boolean
Dim isToHide as Boolean
isNotZero = DataImport.Cells(i, "E").Value <> 0 And DataImport.Cells(i, "F").Value <> 0
isToExpose = DataImport.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Unhide"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = isNotZero and isToExpose
' Purely because I prefer the positive statements
' And now your code is easier to read and self-commenting.
```

Lessons here

- Do the truth tables.
- Identify the patterns.
- Simplify seemingly complex object code with Boolean variables.
- Take it one logical step at time.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. You have made this so much more clearer!

Comment: love that answer

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting the if statements to see if that fixes the issue. Additionally, your logic can be simplified because if value in Column E and F is 0, then we always hide the sheet, no matter what the value in Column I is:

```
If DataImport.Cells(i, "E").Value <> 0 And DataImport.Cells(i, "F").Value <> 0 Then
    If DataImport.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Hide" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = False

    ElseIf DataImport.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Unhide" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = True

    End If

ElseIf DataImport.Cells(i, "E").Value = 0 And DataImport.Cells(i, "F").Value = 0 Then

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = False

End If
```

Also we can further simplify the code using With:

```
With DataImport

If .Cells(i, "E").Value <> 0 And .Cells(i, "F").Value <> 0 Then
    If .Cells(i, "I").Value = "Hide" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = False

    ElseIf .Cells(i, "I").Value = "Unhide" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = True

    End If

ElseIf .Cells(i, "E").Value = 0 And .Cells(i, "F").Value = 0 Then

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = False

End If

End With
```